# How do I replace the file extension of a PathBuf or Path?

Tags: path, rust

My current solution is:

```
let temp = format!(
    "{}.png",
    path.file_stem().unwrap().to_string_lossy());
path.pop();
path.push(&temp);
```

Which is quite ugly, requiring at least 6 function calls and creating an new string.

Is there a more idiomatic, shorter, or more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`PathBuf` provides the method [`set_extension`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.set_extension). It will add the extension if one does not exist yet, or replace it with the new one if it does.

```
let mut path = PathBuf::from("path/to/file");
path.set_extension("png");
assert_eq!(&path.to_string_lossy(), "path/to/file.png");

let mut path = PathBuf::from("path/to/file.jpg");
path.set_extension("png");
assert_eq!(&path.to_string_lossy(), "path/to/file.png");
```